# how to allow apostrophes in regular expressions in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

i want to check string, which should contain only latin letters, dashes and apostrophes.length must be 2-50. everything works, but if a string contains apostrophe, function returns false.

```
private function validName($name)
{
    if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z\'\-]{2,50}$/", $name))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

how to include apostrophe in my regex? i also tried these

```
preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z'-]{2,50}$/", $name)
preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z\'-]{2,50}$/", $name)
preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z'\-]{2,50}$/", $name)
```

but it returns false anyway

UPDATE:

Before run this method, i filter my string with `$name = htmlentities($name, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");`

Comment: Why do you escape the `'` in the pattern?

Comment: for example - some'name. it returns false

Comment: btw, why do you have 2 returns?

Comment: No, [it doesn't](https://regex101.com/r/mZ1bR9/1) (slightly changed the positions, though).

Comment: cause if validation fails it return false, otherwise true

Comment: Pattern works: https://3v4l.org/lZ3P5

Comment: Show the result of `var_dump($name);`, maybe the character isn't an actual apostrophe. Entity, smart quote, etc.

Comment: well, both returns are set inside the same conditional. Maybe some extra bracing would help here. Plus, you seem to be using a class.

Comment: int(0) - result of var_dump. if i enter some-name, it returns true, but if some'name - false

Comment: @chris85 good point.

Comment: @მაზაფაკა you need to show us exactly which animal we're dealing with here, as Chris made a good point on the type(s) of quote used.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: No only the first return is in the conditional.

Comment: AbraCadaver i tried it, but it returns 0 anyway

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte alrighty then ;-) either way, we don't know which animal we're dealing with here exactly. Question's unclear at this point.

Comment: i also echo the result of var_dump($name) parametr, before run preg_match, there's no any additional characters in string, i mean it echo some'name (as it should be).

Comment: before run this method, i filter my string with `$name = htmlentities($name, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");`

Comment: @Fred-ii-: note that it can be shorten to: `return preg_match("/^[a-z'-]{2,50}$/i", $name) && true;`

Comment: It seems you should not use `htmlentities` before checking. `some'name` [turns into `some&#039;name`](http://ideone.com/HntgNu)

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte *sweet!*

Comment: sorry guys if my question is not so clear. i try to validate form. i have name field where user should enter name. in this method(in my question) i try to validate this name. name should be 2 - 50 characters length, only latin letters, dashes and apostrophes

Comment: the less we know, the more time it takes. and so far, all you're doing is giving us bits and pieces as the thread grows bigger. You posted this over 20 mins ago and we're all sitting here "guessing". So, post your full codes. I for one am dropping off here, good luck. [Had you posted this in the first place..](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36923240/include-apostrophe-in-regular-expression-in-php#comment61408310_36923240) in your question, you would have had your answer a lot earlier.

Comment: Don't entitize (if that's a word) it, or decode it on the check. As is you don't have a `some'name`, you have `some&#039;name`. This also will throw off your `50` character limit. View the source of the page and you'll see your actual characters..

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you are right. i already, checked it, it works. enter your comment in answer area, and i mark it as the best

Comment: thank you all guys for reponses

Comment: @chris85 you are right. thank you

Comment: *"i filter my string with $name = htmlentities(...)"* -- no, you're not filtering anything. [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) doesn't filter. It replaces the HTML special characters (`<`, `>`, `&`, `"` and, by your request, `'`) with their HTML representation. This means the value returned by `htmlentities()` **does not** contain any apostrophe (`'`).

Comment: @axiac i mean that by filtering. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `htmlentities` before checking your strings, you may use it *after*.

If you apply `$name = htmlentities($name, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");` to  `some'name`, it will turn into `some&#039;name`.

Also, to shorten the pattern, use

```
preg_match("/^[A-Z'-]{2,50}$/i", $name)
```

The `/i` case insensitive modifier will make the whole pattern case insensitive, and `[A-Z]` will match all upper- and lowercase ASCII letters.

Comment: i also vote up you answear and comment. maybe it will appear a bit late

Comment: Thank you. Comment upvotes do not add to reputation, but some highly upvoted comments can entitle you to a silver badge.