# Regex Single and Double Quote Not Working

Tags: regex, forms, validation

I'm trying to allow letters and common punctuation. After much research I stumbled upon an expression that works perfectly for what I want...except the single and double quotes aren't validating.

This is the string I'm using: `^(?=.*[a-zA-Z0-9])[\w.,!"'\/$ &]+$`

Working String: This is a test, **Im** testing. Test!

Non-Working String: This is a test, **I'm** testing. Test! (No matter where you have a single or double quote.)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: your forward slash needs to be escaped

Comment: @emsimpson92 OP did not forget it, but it does not have to be escaped. It does not really matter much here.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The original post was modified. [On regex101 it errors out if you don't escape it](https://regex101.com/r/B7PDCx/1)

Comment: Then again I suppose it depends on the language, so you might be right

Comment: I only added formatting backticks around the OP code. And regex101 [does not require you to escape backslashes](https://regex101.com/r/B7PDCx/2). You do not have to escape `/` in any language.

Comment: Depends on what you want to use for a delimiter I guess. @Fishman what language are you using?

Comment: @Fishman Try [`^[_.,!/$ &]*[a-zA-Z0-9][\w.,!/$ &]*$`](https://regex101.com/r/B7PDCx/3), just remove `'` and `"`. I also converted the lookahead into a simple consuming pattern.

Comment: @emsimpson92 For this it's just a Wordpress form plugin that has a format/validation field where you can put a Regex. Example here: https://formidableforms.com/knowledgebase/format/#kb-regular-expression-validation

Comment: Do you want to match both strings or only the top one?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Unfortunately that didn't seem to work. I appreciate the help though.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Both strings. I want it to work with or without a single and double quote.

Comment: Try [`^[_.,!/$ &\x22\x27]*[a-zA-Z0-9][\w.,!/$ &\x22\x27]*$`](https://regex101.com/r/B7PDCx/5). Well, or your pattern can be updated as `^(?=.*[a-zA-Z0-9])[\w.,!\x22\x27\/$ &]+$`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It's odd that those don't work, especially the second one following the original pattern. Everything works and validates, until I add a " or ' in the string.

Starting to wonder if there is something else going on. Things that should work, don't seem to be.

Comment: There must be `htmlentities` somewhere. See [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36923240/how-to-allow-apostrophes-in-regular-expressions-in-php/36923827#36923827).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I was able to achieve what I needed, just in a different way. When I looked at the front-end source code and the pattern for the field on the form it didn't look right. What I ended up doing was just allowing everything and excluding what I didn't want. No matter what I did (even escaping) the expressions weren't taking and getting botched somewhere in the system. Doing almost everything with the hex code seemed to do the trick. Thanks for the idea on that by the way!

In case it could help somebody else: https://regex101.com/r/B7PDCx/7

Comment: You're better off allowing only what you want. If you allow everything but a few characters, you're looking at over a million Unicode characters. You can pare down your expression, to allow only in the range of `\x20-\x7e` by using an assertion `^(?:[^#+=@$\x26\x3C\x3E\x5B\x5D\x7B\x7D\x7E](?<=[\x20-\x7e]))+$`. The other way is to allow only what you want (the previous regex equivalent) `^[\x20-\x22\x25\x27-\x2A\x2C-\x3B\x3F\x41-\x5A\x5C\x5E-\x7A\x7C]+$`

Comment: @sln Wow thanks! Didn't think of that. I used the second option and it works perfectly. If I wanted to add a character limit to it, what's the best way to go about that? Let's say I wanted it to be a minimum of 5 and maximum of 200.

Comment: Change the quantifier from `+` ( 1 to many ) to a `{5,200}` which is a _min to max_ range.